# How to solve this equation? $t-ln|t+1|+1 = 0$

Tags: problem-solving

How do I solve this equation?

$$t-ln|t+1|+1 = 0$$

I know it has solution (saw graph).

Comment: For an exact answer, you have to use the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Otherwise, you can approximate it using Newton's method.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this equation, write it as ln|t+1|= t+1 and let x= t+ 1 so that it becomes ln|x|= x.  Now take the exponential of both sides to get $|x|= e^x$ or $|x|e^{-x}= 1$  Finally let y= -x so the equation can be written $-ye^y= 1$ or $ye^y= -1$.

Now to try to solve that you could try. as Toby Mak suggested, either a numerical method or "Lambert's W function" which is defined as the inverse function to $f(x)= xe^x$.

OUCH!  I forgot the absolute value!  The equation is $ye^y= 1$, not -1 so has a solution!